# Questions relative to $scope & controllers

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to play with 2 controllers speaking to each other but I'm stuck with 2 problems/questions:

1. $scope.display is not displayed at first in my view. I wonder why.
2. $scope.display seems to be shared between 2 controllers whereas I read $scope(s) are isolated. I wonder why.
3. I read on stackoverflow the best to communicate between controllers is to use $rootScope.broadcast & $rootScope.on. Does this apply to this example?

**JS**

```
angular.module("superApp", [])
    .controller("headerCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.display = 'hello';
    })
    .controller("homeCtrl", function ($scope) {

    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="superApp">
    <div ng-ctrl="headerCtrl">
        <p>{{ display }}</p>
        <div class="bar hello" ng-show="display == 'hello'"> 
            <span>Hello World<span>
            <button ng-click="display = 'bye'">Say bye</button>
        </div>
        <div class="bar bye" ng-show="display == 'bye'">
            <span>Bye Bye</span>
            <button ng-click="display = 'hello'">Say hello</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-ctrl="homeCtrl" class="content">
        <button ng-click="display = 'bye'">Say bye</button>
        <button ng-click="display = 'hello'">Say hello</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think I'm missing something... Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2756gw7/1/) to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `ng-controller` and not `ng-ctrl`.

```
<div ng-controller="headerCtrl">
```

and

```
<div ng-controller="homeCtrl" class="content">
```

### Why was your code "working"?

When using these directives without a declared controller and its associated scope:

```
ng-click="display = 'bye'"
ng-show="display == 'hello'"
```

You basically affect the $rootScope variables and set a new var 'display' in the $rootScope with the value for each click. That's why it was only shown after first click and does not appear when you initially view the page. None of your controllers were actually being used.

See: [AngularJS Documentation for $rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope)

Comment: code 'working' with rootScope of app, because `ng-app="superApp"` is correct.

Comment: Because your ng-click directive is correct, and works fine. When those directives are executed, the scope for the app gets the variable.

Comment: So my controllers were not called and then "display" was attached to $rootScope, right?

Comment: Yep! That's the ticket. See the documentation's $rootScope reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the ng-ctrl directive, should be ng-controller

```
    <div ng-controller="homeCtrl" class="content">
```